# SwiftUI Handle different frame alignments in Stack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, vstack

I have several views in a VStack/ScrollView using SwiftUI, The text elements I want to be leading (not centered in the view) but the Image I want centered on the Y axis. I've tried using center alignment in the frame but not the image still aligned leading. I tried making the VStack not aligned to leading with the Text aligned leading in the frame, but it just aligned center.

What is the correct way to handle this?

```
var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(alignment: .) {
                        Text(title: viewData.title, font: .bold, size: 22)
                            .padding(.top, 27)
                        Text(title: viewData.body1, font: .regular, size: 16)
                            .padding(.top, 4)
                            .frame(alignment: .center)
                        Image(viewData.headerImageName ?? "")
                            .padding(.top, 80)
                            .frame(width: 88, height: 91, alignment: .center)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 16)

                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.navigateToNext()
                }, label: {
                    Text(title: viewData.buttonTitle, font: .regular, size: 16)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                })
                .frame(width: geo.size.width - 32, height: 48, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color(UIColor.Green))
                .cornerRadius(8)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you show some mock up (design/sketch) of the UI you want to achieve?

Comment: @Asperi I don't have one but it should look like: Header Text - aligned leading, Body Test - aligned Leading, Image - aligned center

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59657845/12299030?

Comment: This [SwiftUI Labs post](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/) is very helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to get the alignment you're looking for. I've provided a few simplified examples below:

### Option 1

```
/// Text and Image frame will be leading aligned
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("Title")
    
    Text("Body text")
    
    Image(systemName: "gear")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        /// Width limited to 88 points
        .frame(width: 88)
        /// Put in the center of another frame that fills the width.
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
```

### Option 2

```
/// Text frames and Image will be center aligned.
VStack {
    Text("Title")
        /// Put on the leading edge of a frame that fills the width
        /// This frame is then aligned to the center of the VStack.
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    
    Text("Body text")
        /// Put on the leading edge of a frame that fills the width
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    
    Image(systemName: "gear")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(width: 88)
}
```

### Option 3

```
/// HStack and Image will be center aligned.
VStack {
    HStack {
        /// Text will be leading aligned.
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Title")
            Text("Body text")
        }
        
        /// Spacer takes up remaining horizontal space.
        Spacer()
    }
    
    Image(systemName: "gear")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(width: 88)
}
```

Additionally, the GeometryReader is not required on the overall frame.

This line:

```
.frame(width: geo.size.width - 32, height: 48, alignment: .center)
```

Can be replaced by:

```
.padding(.horizontal, 32)
.frame(height: 48)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an approach (and IMHO you don't need geometryReader):

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("viewData.title")
                        .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .bold))
                        .padding(.top, 27)
                    
                    Text("viewData.body1")
                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .regular))
                        .padding(.top, 4)
                    
                    Image(systemName: "sun.max")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 88, height: 91)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center) // here
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                //                        self.navigateToNext()
            }, label: {
                Text("viewData.buttonTitle")
                    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .regular))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            })
            .frame(height: 48)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color(UIColor.green))
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
``
```